# Could not creat C function using array

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, pointers

i am trying to make a c function for hex to binary conversion, but getting weird errors, I am pretty new to C. Trying to pass the string but no luck getting bunch of errors.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<string.h>
char *hexc(char hex[10]);

int main(){
char hex[10];
//char bin[1000];
scanf("%c",&hex[10]);
printf("binary value: %s",hexc(hex[10]));}

char *hexc(char hex[10])
{
const char binary[16][5] = {"0000", "0001", "0010", "0011",      "0100",  "0101","0110", "0111", "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110","1111"};
const char digits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
const char input[100]; // input value
memcpy (input,hex,100);
char res[1024];
res[0] = '\0';
int p = 0;
int value =0;

while(input[p])
    {
        const char *v = strchr(digits, tolower(input[p]));
        if(v[0]>96){
            value=v[0]-87;
        }
        else{
            value=v[0]-48;
        }
        if (v){
            strcat(res, binary[value]);
        }
        p++;
    }
    printf("binary: %s", res); 
    return res;}
```

list of error, tried multiple google search but no luck.

```
test2.c: In function ‘main’:
test2.c:9:1: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘hexc’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
 printf("binary value: %s",hexc(hex[10]));}
 ^
test2.c:3:7: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 char *hexc(char hex[10]);
       ^
test2.c: In function ‘hexc’:
test2.c:16:1: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘memcpy’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
 memcpy (input,hex,100);
 ^
In file included from test2.c:2:0:
/usr/include/string.h:46:14: note: expected ‘void * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
 extern void *memcpy (void *__restrict __dest, const void *__restrict __src,
              ^
test2.c:36:28: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
 printf("binary: %s", res); return res;}
```

Comment: Read several good C programming books

Comment: Here: `scanf("%c",&hex[10]);`, out of bounds access. This is undefined behaviour and all bets are off. You will have to fix that.

Comment: Which error from the compiler is it that you don't understand?

Comment: `hexc(hex[10]))` is also out of bounds access.

Comment: Protip: A question is a sequence of words ending with a question mark crafted so we know what information you're seeking. Your question is absent, so we don't know what information you're seeking. Perhaps you meant to ask a question about the warnings that you presumably don't understand? Rather than forcing us to treat you like you don't understand *anything* (do you really want us to treat you that way?), why not tell us which words from those warnings are causing your confusion? This would save us lots of time and possibly save you lots of emotional distress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> // add to use tolower function
#include<string.h>
char *hexc(char hex[10]); // note: 10 in here is ignored by compiler

int main(){
    char hex[10];
    //char bin[1000];
    //scanf("%c",&hex[10]); // hex[10] is out of range
    scanf("%9s",hex);
    //printf("binary value: %s",hexc(hex[10]));} // hex[10] is out of range
    printf("binary value: %s",hexc(hex));
    return 0; // it is better to return something
}

char *hexc(char hex[10])
{
    const char binary[16][5] = {"0000", "0001", "0010", "0011",      "0100",  "0101","0110", "0111", "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110","1111"};
    const char digits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    char input[100]; // input value // don't use const here. it is not needed and do harm.
    //memcpy (input,hex,100); // 100 is too large to read from hex
    memcpy (input,hex,10);
    static char res[1024]; // make this static so that it can be read from the main function safely (this may not be thread-safe)
    res[0] = '\0';
    int p = 0;
    int value =0;

    while(input[p])
    {
        const char *v = strchr(digits, tolower(input[p]));
        if(v[0]>96){
            value=v[0]-87;
        }
        else{
            value=v[0]-48;
        }
        if (v){
            strcat(res, binary[value]);
        }
        p++;
    }
    printf("binary: %s", res); 
    return res;
}
```

Comment: thanks @MikeCAT, i tried your changes and left with one error, `net.c:43:5: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
     return res;`

Comment: This code [do work with no compile errors or warnings](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XiJA52qymBbJtYge). Please check your code again.

Answer (score 0):

**1.**  `scanf("%c",&hex[10]);`

This is **wrong** and causing **undefined behaviour** . array indexing starts from `0` , so highest index you can access is `9` not `10` .

Use `fgets` to take input -

```
fgets(hex,10,stdin);
```

**2.** In `printf`  when you make a call

```
 hexc(hex[10]));              // hex[10] index out of bounds
```

`hexc` expects a `char array` and pass it a single character.

Just pass array `hex` to it - `hexc(hex))` in `printf`

**3.** Don't make `input` constant.

```
    char input[100]; //   char array (without const)
    memcpy (input,hex,100);
```